# Overlap between onEdit(e) and onChange(e) triggers in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

According to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers:

> onEdit(e) runs when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet.

On the other hand, `onChange(e)` has the following possible values for `changeType` according to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events:

> The type of change (EDIT, INSERT_ROW, INSERT_COLUMN, REMOVE_ROW, REMOVE_COLUMN, INSERT_GRID, REMOVE_GRID, FORMAT, or OTHER).

So:

Why does the `onEdit(e)` trigger fire up when I'm merely changing cell borders? Is changing the cell(s) format considered a change in value?

Comment: Perhaps you can go to this [page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) scroll to the top right and click on feedback and  ask them to explain onEdit  and onChange better.

Comment: If you are looking for help with your script I suggest you to post a new question including a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This is most likely a bug.

Either `onEdit` is firing when it shouldn't, or the documentation should be updated to include border changes. Based on the current documentation, it's clear it should only trigger when values change.

For future reference, posting here the corresponding Issue Tracker (which you probably filed):

- [Conflict between onEdit and onChange triggers](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213928736)

Comment: This is indeed a bug as confirmed by the comment on the ticket. Thank you!